# Strip values from a string into a row format?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, split

This is a fixed string format i get - `('CA','CO','IL','KS')`

How can i convert this into the below row format in Oracle.

```
OUTPUT DESIRED:
--------
CA
CO
IL
KS
```

How can i make it like above output using regexp in Oracle? I cannot edit the string values to add extra quotes.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I was using this-

l_sql_stmt := 'select regexp_substr((replace(replace(replace(' || l_state_filter(i) || ',chr(40)),chr(41)), chr(39))), ''[^,]+'', 1, level) as state from dual
                                   connect by level <= regexp_count(' || l_state_filter(i) || ', ''[,]'') + 1';

l_state_filter has this format value - ('CA','CO','IL','KS') and this code is erroring out because of quotes issue. How can i modify this code to get this?

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it